# Is AImage the native counterpart to android.media.Image

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass `android.media.Image` to native code and was wondering if `AImage` is the native counterpart. I can't find a function that will convert `jobject` of an `Image` into `AImage`. Something like `ANativeWindow_toSurface()` but in the other direction and for Image -> AImage.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm trying to create `android.media.Image` instances that are backed by a HardwareBuffer/OpenGL texture, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I did not. I at least cannot find an equivalent to `android.media.Image` in native code. I'm curently just using a DirectBuffer which you can extract from the image and pass to native code. Otherwise, you will have to call the Java API in native code which is tedious.

Comment: Hey - do you maybe have any experience with ImageWriter? I am using ImageWriter + MediaRecorder right now, and for some reason I cannot pass images through to MediaRecorder's surface. Do you maybe have any idea why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152531